# Timers In A Game

Tags: java, timer

Im trying to code a 2D java game. I have `init()`, `render()`, `update()` methods as usual. The thing I want to figure out is, I would like to have timers attached to objects. For example a powerup randomly spawns in the map, but it should exist for 5 seconds. Or when the user hits the "Play" button, I would like to make him wait for 3 seconds, and at the same time do the background work (load resources, create the scene etc). I mean I would like to have the time counters work at the background, while I'm doing the stuff normally in the game at the same time. How can I implement this? Any helps, even simple ideas would be appreciated!

**Edit:** I'm using slick2D library and Graphics class for drawing to the screen.

Comment: For better answers, more information would help. For instance, what GUI library are you using? Are you using a game engine library? How are you implementing your game loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a timer there are multiple ways to do so, as stated previously there is the:

Thread.sleep(milli);

or another way I commonly use is to create a new class and make a Timer there using a while loop:

```
public class Timer implements Runnable {

    private long startTime, runTime;

    public Timer(long runTime){//set runtime
         this.runTime = runTime;
    }

    public void run(){
       startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//gets system's current time in milliseconds
       while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < runTime ){//loops until the current time - the start time is less then the specified run time. 
        //Runs this
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to "pause" execution. These are two:

- you can use `delay(milliseconds)` from the `Robot` class
- or the static method `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)`

Comment: The thing is I don't want to pause the execution, I need to keep time track of some objects that appear in the game. That's why game has to continue when i use time counters